# How to add padding to a brush being use as a slider in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using a brush as slider to select dates http://jsfiddle.net/8dLx727L/4/
based on this example http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6452972.

In both my JsFiddle and the example at bl.ocks when the brush handle is at the beginning or at the end 
of the range, the clickable area on the handle is cut off by about 30%-40% because it is outside of the range.

Any idea on how to make the whole handle clickable?

```
var format = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d");
var endDate = d3.time.monday.round(new Date())

var x = d3.time.scale()
.domain([format.parse("2013-06-25"), endDate])
.nice(d3.time.monday)
.range([0, width])
.clamp(true);

var brush = d3.svg.brush()
.x(x)
.on("brush", brushed)
.on("brushend", brushended);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 44 + "," + 20 + ")");


var expr = function (i)  { 
return i === 6 || i == 12; 
}

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
.call(d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickValues(d3.time.month.range( format.parse("2013-06-25"), endDate).filter(function(d, i) {
  return expr(i); }))
//.ticks(d3.time.month, 6) format.parse("2013-06-25"), endDate
.tickFormat(function (d, i) {
return monthYearFormat(d);
})
.tickSize(0)
.tickPadding(30))

d3.select('path')
.attr('d', lineGenerator(brushBackgroundCoords))

var slider = svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "slider")
.call(brush);

slider.selectAll(".extent,.resize")
.remove();

slider.select(".background")
.attr("height", height);

var handle = slider.append("circle")
.attr("class", "handle")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
.attr("r", 22);

handle.append("rect")
 .attr("class", "handle-lable")
 .attr("width", 90)
 .attr("height",44)
 .attr("transform", "translate(0,44)")

var innerHandle = slider.append("circle")
.attr("class", "inner-handle")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height / 2 + ")")
.attr("r", 11);
```

Answer (score 0):

On the CSS file, I had to remove pointer-event: none,

```
.slider .handle {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: #000;
    stroke-opacity: .5;
    stroke-width: 1.25px;
    cursor: move;
}
```

Mike Bostock solved this.